# AngularJS accessing $scope outside of method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my method inside a controller, i want to access the $scope.oldcats  outside the below given method. 
Using `console.info($scope.oldcats);` inside the method, outputs the data, 
but using `console.info($scope.oldcats);` outside function display `undefined`.

```
$scope.loadPost = function() { //Issues a GET request to /api/post/:id to get a Post to update
    $scope.posts = Post.get({ id:$stateParams.id}, function(response){
       $scope.posts = response.data;
       $scope.posts.selcats = response.data.categories;
       var cats = $scope.posts.categories;
       $.each(cats, function(arrayID,group) {
           $scope.allCats.push(group.id);
       });
       $scope.oldcats = $scope.allCats; // <- i want to access it
       console.info($scope.oldcats); // <- output displays data
   });
  };

  $scope.loadPost(); // Load a Post which can be edited on UI

  console.info($scope.oldcats); // <- output display undefined
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made several mistakes and you should use promises:

```
$scope.loadPost = function(){ //Issues a GET request to /api/post/:id to get a Post to update        
    $scope.posts = function(){
       var deferred = $q.defer();
       Post.get({ id:$stateParams.id}, function(response){
           $scope.posts = response.data;
           $scope.posts.selcats = response.data.categories;
           var cats = $scope.posts.categories;
           $.each(cats, function(arrayID,group) {
               $scope.allCats.push(group.id);
           });
           $scope.oldcats = $scope.allCats; // <- i want to access it
           deferred.resolve($scope.oldcats);
           console.info($scope.oldcats); // <- output displays data
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  };
  return $scope.posts;
};

$scope.loadPost()().then(function(res){
    console.info(res);
});
```

Comment: i want to assign 'res' data to '$scope.selectedCategory'   outside the function

Comment: You can do that `$scope.selectedCategory = res;` instead of `console.info(res);`, because `$scope` is a global object inside controller. It is the only way. At this case you can't just write something like  `$scope.selectedCategory = $scope.loadPost();`. Or I don't understand something, what do you mean about "outside the function", what is this function(loadPost, posts or something else)?

Comment: my bad language sorry... i mean accessing $scope.selectedCategory outside '$scope.loadPost()().then(function(res){
      $scope.selectedCategory = res;
 });'    it shows undefined

Comment: Where you checked that it is undefined, inside last construction?

Comment: I created simple [examle](http://plnkr.co/edit/JuQ6QE4qI9CmirzPmilP?p=preview)(Post.get I simulated by means on $interval service) I think it will help you.

Comment: 'Resource {$promise: d, $resolved: false}
$promise: d
$resolved: true
data: Array[2]
0: 1
1: 3
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
message: "category listed"
__proto__: Resource' i have the following output for my data.. i want only the data that is 1 and 3 in array ? how can we achieve it ?? sorry for bothering u .. as i am new to angular

Comment: I don't understand. First, what is _Resource_, is it `response`? And _data_, as I assume, is `response.data`? _1 and 3 in array_ - i.e. you want to take items at 1 and 3 position, but you have only array of 2 items, if you want to take items with 1 and 3 values, I don't understand is there sence for that at all.

Comment: I completely confused about what happening, maybe this [variant](https://jsfiddle.net/xj7z7omd/1/) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The `console.info` outside the function is called before the API call gets finished. Therefore it logs `undefined`. But the console inside the function is being called after the API call gets finished.
This is called asynchronous behaviour.
Have a look at [Promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

This `thinkster` tutorial will be helpful to understand asynchronous behaviour better: [Thinkster-understand promises](https://www.google.com.kw/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj5muOOv93KAhUKWBoKHT_oAEUQFgggMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fthinkster.io%2Fa-better-way-to-learn-angularjs%2Fpromises&usg=AFQjCNEu5pOpMNQWpOGbFn4P_0iFgBXRhQ&sig2=fOU9oSYLhHmSORkw3JnezQ)

Comment: using console.log also shows undefined.. and $scope variable have no data

Comment: Anything you use will show you undefined because the API call has not finished.

Comment: how can we access that $scope.oldcats variable outside of  the method ?

Comment: You can access it in the same way you are doing now, but you will have to wait for the api call to finishe. And for that you will need promises which will notify you once the call gets finished.